# onChange event listener being called everytime window.onload function instantiated

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate null input for dropdown selection, but the onchange event is triggered without any change of selection on dropdown list, when the window.onLoad() is instantiated.

Comment: Can you provide your code? I suspect the ```onchange``` event is tied to the wrong element.

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can provide your snipped code for your problem. You can try to add the

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener);
target.addEventListener(type, listener, options);
target.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
```

On the other hand, you might want to try:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Also, you can learn more here: [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)